# Beginning Java Decision Structures and The Math Object Switch Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Okay, this is what I'm told to do 
1.Have the user enter two integersto use for the following tasks.
2.Write a simple if then structure to to check the value of a number entered by
the user and display whether it is greater than 0, greater than 10 or negative.
3.Write a decision structure that uses a boolean expression to determine and
display whether number one and number two are positive.
4.Use a switch statement to check the value of number two from 1 to 5 and
display the appropriate value. The structure should exit when the value is
found. Include an action to display value not found if it isn't found.

I've gotten to 4 myself but cant figure out how to make the switch statement exit if the second number is no 1-5. I know how to display the "value not found" but done know how to tell it to display it is 1-5 is not entered. Let me know a simple way of doing this thanks! This is what I have so far:

```
package ICS4UIReviewTest;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class PartOneDecisionStructuresAndMathObject {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int int1, int2;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
        int1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
        int2 = input.nextInt();

        if (int1 > 0 && int1 < 10){
            System.out.println("The first number is > 0.");
            } else {
                 if (int1 > 10){
                     System.out.println("The first number is > 10.");
                } else {
                  System.out.println("The first number is negative.");
                    }
                }
            if (int1 > 0 && int2 > 0) {
             System.out.println("The 1st & 2nd number are postiive.");
                }
        switch (int2) {
            case 1: System.out.println("The second number entered is 1."); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("The second number entered is 2."); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("The second number entered is 3."); break;
            case 4: System.out.println("The second number entered is 4."); break; 
            case 5: System.out.println("The second number entered is 5."); break;
                }

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the fall-through in `switch` (and add a `default` case):

```
switch (int2) {
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
    case 3: 
    case 4: 
    case 5: System.out.println("The second number entered is " + int2 + ".");
            break;
    default: System.out.println("Number entered not between 1 and 5");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default`. If none of the cases are matched, then the default clause is executed.

```
   switch (int2) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("The second number entered is 1.");
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("The second number entered is 2."); 
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("The second number entered is 3."); 
            break;
        case 4: 
            System.out.println("The second number entered is 4."); 
            break; 
        case 5: 
            System.out.println("The second number entered is 5."); 
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("Number not in range"); 
   }
```

Comment: Correct, but you don't need `break` in `default` case.